# fastest method to solve a quadratic equation modulo p^N

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What is the fastest method to solve a quadratic equation

$ax^2 + bx + c = 0 (mod p^N) $

where p is prime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start by multiplying by the inverse of $a$, to make your lead coefficient $1$: $x^2+Bx+C\equiv 0$. Then you can complete the square, replacing your coefficient $B$ with $B-p^N$ if that helps you see how to understand $\frac{B}{2}$.

This will tell you what number has to be a quadratic residue, and you can work on finding its square root. For that, you probably want to find the square root mod $p$ first, and then use Hensel's lifting lemma until you get to $p^N$.

Does that answer your question, or do you need more details on any of those steps?

Comment: Please tell me what is the fastest method of finding square root mod p. I will also appreciate if you guide me to an novice's explanation for Hensel's lifting lemma.

Comment: First, you need to know whether your number even is a square - Legendre symbols are good for that. If it is, you can use a primitive root to find a square root for it. Whether this is really quicker than trial-and-error will vary from prime to prime. For the Hensel stuff, let me see what I can either find, or write up quickly...

Comment: This is a pretty good resource on Hensel: https://brilliant.org/wiki/hensels-lemma/

Comment: Do you mean "replacing your coefficient $B$ with $p^N+B$"? With the minus there, I think you change the polynomial.

Comment: @Arthur, indeed, thank you. Edited. I did mean a minus, but not that way.

Comment: Of course, it's also possible that $a$ is divisible by some smaller power of $p$, in which case you first solve a linear equation mod that power of $p$...

Comment: Why do you want to make the coefficient even?  If $p$ is odd, "even" is meaningless: $2$ is invertible mod $p^N$.  If $p = 2$, adding a power of $2$ won't make it even.

Comment: @RobertIsrael, because when someone isn't particularly used to this, they might find completing the square easier that way. Quick, what's 15/2 mod 19? Did you add or subtract 19 in your head to come up with the answer?